# Enter VR in Aframe via eye-gazing button

Tags: javascript, button, aframe

I enabled the vr-mode-ui and I would like to have a button inside my aframe scene which enters vr mode by click. My problem is my js gives me a TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null and I don`t know why!

```
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('enter', {
  init: function () {
  }
}); 

document.getElementById('startbutton').addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    scene.enterVR(true);
});
</script>

<a-scene id="scene" antialias="true"; cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" vr-mode-ui="enabled: true">

<a-assets>
<img id="startscreen" src="start_overlay.png">  
</a-assets>

<!-- Environment -->

<a-sky id="environment" radius="9" rotation="0 -90 0"; material="shader: flat; src: #xxx"></a-sky>

<!-- Camera + cursor + Startscreen + Interaction-->
<a-entity look-controls>
    <a-entity id="start">
            <a-plane id="startbutton" class="link"; height="0.5"; width="5"; position="0 -0.7 -2" rotation="0 0 0" color="#ffbff0">

            <a-text align="center" value="START" width="10" color="#e143a1"></a-text>
            </a-plane>

    </a-entity>

    <a-entity id="cam" camera rotation="0 0 0" mouse-cursor>                
        <a-cursor id="cursor" color="red"
          animation__click="property: scale; startEvents: click; from: 0.1 0.1 0.1; to: 1 1 1; dur: 150"
          animation__fusing="property: fusing; startEvents: fusing; from: 1 1 1; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1; dur: 1500"
          event-set__1="_event: mouseenter; color: white"
          event-set__2="_event: mouseleave; color: red"
          fuse="true"
          raycaster="objects: .link"></a-cursor>
    </a-entity>

</a-entity>

</a-scene>
```

I don`t know why my button isn`t recognized by the js-script!

Could someone help, please! Cheers, Can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button may not be present in the DOM by the time the code is executed. Either :
1) throw the code into a AFRAME component, 
2) place the code after the HTML body, or 
3) place it in a `window.onload` callback:

```
window.onload = function() {
  doSomething();
};
```

---

Also, as you can see in the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/scene.html), the proper method is to call `enterVR()`, or `exitVR()` on the scene element. Make sure the `scene` reference you use actually holds the scene element.

Comment: also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t) anwser